# MySQL created_timestamp more than updated_timestamp

Tags: mysql, django

I am using Django ORM and have set auto_now and auto_now_add as follows..

```
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=True, default=None)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

I have some records where updated_at is less than created_at by around upto 50 seconds..

**NOTE**
I have only one MySQL master machine and multiple Django servers.. How is it possible to have created_timestamp more than updated_timestamp..

Comment: Those field definitions are overly complex. `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` are mutually exclusive; you don't need to set `auto_now_add` on a field that has `auto_now`. Also, since both fields will be set on save, there is no point declaring them as blank or null, or defining a default.

Answer (score 1):

Setting auto_now/auto_now_add fields happens in the application, not in the database (in `DateTimeField.pre_save`).

You might have some really weird race condition, but the easiest explanation is probably that the clocks on your web servers are not in sync.

Answer (score 0):

**You are defining both `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` in `updated_at` datetime field which is wrong.**

As per Django docs on [DateTime field:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#datefield)

> The options auto_now_add, auto_now, and default are mutually
>   exclusive. Any combination of these options will result in an error.

It should be something like:

```
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=False, null=True, default=None)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Note:**

[**`auto_now`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now): Use this option for setting 'last_modified' timestamps

[**`auto_now_add:`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) Use this option for setting the 'creation' timestamp.